# How to determine whether or not EnvDTE.Project object represents a C/C++ project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-package

I have a `Project` instance, and I don't understand how to find out the project type/language. Specifically, I need to check for a C/C++ project.

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx) seem lacking.

Previously, another person added the following bit of magic to my open-source VS extension, and it worked in VS2013-2015:

```
private static bool isVisualCppProject(object project)
{
    Type projectObjectType = project.GetType();
    var projectInterface = projectObjectType.GetInterface("Microsoft.VisualStudio.VCProjectEngine.VCProject");
    return projectInterface != null;
}

   ...

isVisualCppProject(project.Object);
```

But it no longer works in VS 2017 RC. And I would gladly get rid of this runtime reflection magic and un-typed `object` and `dynamic` instead of `Project` - the code is already getting unmaintainable because of this.

Comment: There is `Kind` property(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.kind.aspx) for `envdte.project`. It is GUID. There are predefined Project Kinds in `PrjKind` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vslangproj.prjkind.aspx) but it seems there is no property for c/c++. I guess you can get that GUID and it will be same for all c/c++ projects.

Comment: @AramKocharyan: I did see `Kind`, but there's no list of possible "kinds", nor any guarantee that it is indeed static across various machines, installations and VS versions...

Comment: @Violet-Giraffe: Do you resolve the issue? if the issue still exists, please feel free let me know.

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT: I believe your answer will serve, but I want to actually implement it before I accept the answer. And that requires a fair bit of careful refactoring of my extension.

Answer (score 2):

you can determine project type via project extension name, and the following demo for your reference.

```
    DTE2 dte = (DTE2)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
            Solution2 solution = (Solution2)dte.Solution;

            foreach (Project p in solution.Projects)
            {

                string[] projectName = p.FullName.Split('.');

                if (projectName.Length > 1)
                {
                   string fileExt = projectName[projectName.Length-1];

                    if (fileExt == "vcxproj")
                    {
                        //is c/c++ porject
                    }
                }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The EnvDTE.Project.Kind is the first place to look, as mentioned in the comments above. See [HOWTO: Guess the type of a Visual Studio project from an add-in or macro](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507014231/https://www.mztools.com/Articles/2007/MZ2007014.aspx)

There is a list of some well-known GUIDs, see [INFO: List of known project type Guids](https://web.archive.org/web/20210726052235/https://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/mz2008017.aspx).

You are probably interested in {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}. But a project may have various sub-types, in which case multiple GUIDs are applied to it. For example MVC + C#. See [HOWTO: Get the project flavor (subtype) of a Visual Studio project from an add-in](https://web.archive.org/web/20210726043623/https://www.mztools.com/Articles/2007/MZ2007016.aspx)

The EnvDTE.Project.Kind contains the main project type and it is not guaranteed that e.g. the C++ GUID will be stored in this property. The safest way is to retrieve all GUIDs applied to a project. Use the **GetProjectTypeGuids** method from the last link. You'll get the list of all GUID and then you'll just test if it contains {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}.